# Hcxpcap tool missing?

Tags: wireless, 20.04, tools, aircrack-ng, hash

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my laptop.
I was using hcxdumptool to capture pmkids.
After i captured them. I wanted to filter the output using hcxpcaptool, but i found that "Command Not Found ".
From where can i get it installed. I have got hcxdumptool & hcxtool installed.
from https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxtools https://github.com/ZerBea/hcxdumptool
I installed them  on the system.
Please anyone can tell me how can i install hcxpcaptool it seems to be not installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this [utility](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=groovy&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=hcxpcaptool) [is available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/hcxtools) for Ubuntu 20.10 and newer.

But you can simply download its deb-package to install on Ubuntu 20.04 manually with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/hcxtools/hcxtools_6.0.2-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./hcxtools_6.0.2-1_amd64.deb
```

and then launch the utility by `hcxpcaptool`.

Answer (score 4):

`hcxpcaptool` was superceded by `hcxpcapngtool`.  I think both were once available in `hcxtools` but now only the ng version is.

The new one seems to be mostly backwards compatible so you should be able to use it for whatever you needed `hcxpcaptool`.

In my case, after installing `hcxtools`, `wifite` was still complaining that `hcxpcaptool` was missing.  I created this symlink to convince wifite that they're the same.

```
# ln -s /usr/local/bin/hcxpcapngtool /usr/local/bin/hcxpcaptool
```

Wifite was able to start after that, *and* perform PKMID captures.  I doubt that the new tool is completely backwards compatible with the old one, so consider this a work-around and not a fix.